# Partial memoization in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, memoization

I'm trying to find a good way to memoize a function for only part of its domain (non-negative integers) in Haskell, using `Data.MemoCombinators`.

```
import Data.MemoCombinators

--approach 1

partFib n | n < 0 = undefined
          | otherwise = integral fib n where
  fib 0 = 1
  fib 1 = 1
  fib k = partFib (k-1) + partFib (k-2)

--approach 2

partFib2 n | n < 0 = undefined
           | otherwise = fib n
fib = integral fib'
  where
    fib' 0 = 1
    fib' 1 = 1
    fib' n = partFib2 (n-1) + partFib2 (n-2)
```

Approach 1 is how I would like to do it, however, it doesn't seem to work. I assume this is because the `fib` function is "recreated" every time `partFib` is called, throwing away the memoization. `fib` doesn't depend on the input of `partFib`, so you would assume that the compiler could hoist it, but apparently GHC doesn't work that way.

Approach 2 is how I end up doing it. Eerk, a lot of ugly wiring.

Does anybody know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite sure what's "ugly" to your eye, but you can have proper memoization while using only a single top-level identifier by lifting the memoization operation out of the function of `n`.

```
partFib3 = \n -> if n < 0 then undefined else fib' n
    where fib 0 = 1
          fib 1 = 1
          fib k = partFib3 (k-1) + partFib3 (k-2)
          fib' = integral fib
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better than what I had. Nothing is really that "ugly" I just want the definition to look as similar to the naive Fibonacci implementation as possible.

Comment: Why does this make a difference? Isn't `f n = e` semantically exactly the same as `f = \n -> e`?

Comment: @Dan, semantically, yes.  But memoization is getting into operational territory. The `n` in the former is scoped over the `where` clause whereas the `n` in the latter is not, thus changing how the thunks in the where clause are shared.

Comment: @Dan, this recent article about sharing variable bindings has a bit more detail: http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2011/09/sharing-in-haskell.html

Comment: Chapter 7 of Richard Bird's *Thinking functionally with Haskell* is also a great read on the topic.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm what about separating things a bit:

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib x = doFib (x-1) + doFib (x-2)

memFib = Memo.integral fib

doFib n | n < 0 = fib n
        | otherwise memFib n
```

Now you need to use doFib.

Comment: Thanks. I like this as well. It separates the function definition cleanly from the definition of what is memoized.

Answer (score 4):

There is a combinator in the library for this purpose:

> ```
> switch :: (a -> Bool) -> Memo a -> Memo a -> Memo a
> ```
>
> `switch p a b` uses the memo table `a` whenever `p` gives true and the memo table `b` whenever `p` gives false.

Recall that `id` is technically a memoizer (which does not memoize :-), so you can do:

```
partFib = Memo.switch (< 0) id Memo.integral fib'
    where
    ...
```

Comment: By "a memoizer (which does not memoize :-)" you mean that its type is `Memo a`, so the type system will allow you to use it as a memoizer?